# Validation on input fields in popup and view of popup Ionic

Tags: cordova, validation, ionic-framework

I am creating Cordova Ionic app. How can I apply validations on Input fields in popup. I have two fields: Width and Height. I want to apply validation on both the fields.

Validations will be:

Min value : 10 mm
Max Value : 1000 mm

Also I'm not aware why the view of popup is like this (image given below of Android tablet). The input field is not shown. The buttons are gone when keyboard is open.

When keyboard is not open :

[image]

When keyboard is open :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to set a maximum and minimum value for an input field. You can achieve this with HTML by doing the following:

```
<input name="width" type="number" min="10" max="1000">
```

You can also use [Angular's ngChange directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to detect when the input changes and disallow the user from going below 10 or above 1000, here is an (incomplete) example:

**Controller**

```
$scope.input = {
  width: 10,
  height: 10
};

$scope.inputChanged = function(input) {
  if(input >= 10 && input <= 1000) {
    // This is valid input and should be left untouched.
  } else if(input < 10) {
    // If it is lower, set it to 10.
  } else if(input > 1000) {
    // If it is higher, set it to 1000.
  }
};
```

**View**

```
<input name="height" type="number" min="10" max="1000" ng-model="input.height" ng-change="inputChanged(input.height)">
<input name="width" type="number" min="10" max="1000" ng-model="input.width" ng-change="inputChanged(input.width)">
```

The above example is incomplete on purpose, simply because I do not think it is necessary to use JavaScript, the HTML should suffice depending on what you are looking for. Additionally, you can also validate the input when the user submits the values and show an error.

Comment: Thank you for the validation...any solution regarding data hide issue?

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix I have no idea and cannot help you without code. I would recommend you open a new question if you are still experiencing that issue. If you are satisfied with the answer I have provided, I would also like to ask you to accept it as an answer.